# Should the Critic badge be removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

The [Critic badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic) could cause users to downvote good posts. Should it be removed?

Comment: Even if you could provide evidence of this happening, it wouldn't matter because people are free to vote as they wish, provided it is within the rules of this site.  A hypothetical about what could happen thus doesn't really matter.

Comment: I really don't think anyone finds it much of a problem to find a bad post to downvote. Given so much chaff, why would anyone waste their first downvote on wheat?

Comment: *"The critic badge could cause users to down vote good posts."* Citation required. Seriously, can you provide *one* example?

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder how many downvoters here got the critic badge from this post?...

Comment: Did I not mention this is a discussion?

Comment: @Miroslav There's nothing to discuss.

Comment: Probably no one got badges from voting on this post. Regular visitors of Meta downvote early and often, as well they should. Downvotes here don't cost reputation to the poster, and they are often used to signal agreement/disagreement as well as basic quality. So making this a [discussion] is not a magic "no-downvotes" shield. People simply disagree that this should be implemented, and thus there is nothing to discuss. It's a lot faster and less messy to convey community consensus via votes, as was done here.

Comment: Well sorry then ;)

Comment: I think it should be removed. AFAICT it serves no purpose and only encourages negativity.

Comment: @seph it absolutely serves a purpose: to teach new users about a feature. Voting (both up *and down*) is critical to how this site works. If you feel downvotes “encourage negativity” then perhaps this site is not for you. Our whole reputation for quality answers is built upon the voting system and will not change.

Answer (score 26):

No.  You only get it **once** and it's a bronze badge.  In general, bronze badges are meant to introduce entry-level features and functionality to users in a way that makes it rewarding for them.

Besides, if a question or answer is *truly* good, it'll get upvoted higher than it'll ever get downvoted.

Comment: If anyone wonders why this got a down vote, it is mine :( . But I only later noticed I already had the Critic badge. .... sorry ...needs moar coffee .,.