# Why'd my Meta flag on a comment which should *really* have been its own answer get declined?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, moderation

Someone's gonna have to explain this one to me.

[My answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356116/1079354) received a new comment after a few years.  This particular comment seems like it'd be better served in an answer, but it also seemed like it was entirely conversational and thus orthogonal to my *answer*.

So, I flagged it, but it was declined.

Not sure why.  At *best* it should be its own answer.

Comment: The flag was “no longer needed”. You flagged it on your own answer. Sometimes people do that to quell critiques of their answers. In any case; was the comment truly obsolete?

Comment: It wasn't a critique.  It was just flat-out orthogonal, @GeorgeStocker.  Comments have been deleted on Meta for weaker reasons than that.  Clearly, the commentator wanted to disagree but that disagreement should've been contained in an actual answer as opposed to taking what is actually a toxic position against the functionality of a site in a capacity where ***I*** am unable to disagree with it.  In other words, *I don't feel like getting into a comment war.*  Get them to post an answer which they then have to defend in the same way.

Comment: It's not useful to downvote this question, when the OP is doing exactly what the [new proposal for comment moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387883/7795130) asked us to do: Flag comments that are tangential to the question/answer, flag more often, and if "a staff member or a moderator [is] saying something that you think contradicts policy..., please make a new meta question." Declining this flag appears to be against policy, so it's completely appropriate to ask this question.

Comment: @DavyM:  *Honestly* I don't care if someone wants to downvote this.  Let 'em.  The people who this is addressed to can find this if they wish to; this honestly isn't a thing that we mere mortals or Metahounds can answer, anyway.

Comment: I guess the offending comment/s have been already removed? There are some hints about a missing part of the conversation both in answer and question, but nothing else.

Comment: @yivi: They were removed at a few points in time between this question and now.

Comment: Also, goodness gracious do I have a lot to catch up on...

Comment: Re: _"Comments have been deleted on meta for weaker reasons"_. I have not seen the comment in question, but I wanted to mention that I think I've perceived a change in the amount of wantonly deleted comments since the deletion extravaganza from a few weeks ago. Waters seem to be quieter (although it is also true that several regulars seem to have fled the site, which might have had an effect as well). So maybe maybe we should adjust our expectations to a more normal situation, not to the "all comments are going away asap".

Comment: @yivi: I left a picture of it in the revision history.  You can see the link to the comment for yourself in there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "No longer needed", despite its unfortunate name, is not meant to be a synonym of "obsolete". It was created as a superset of the old "obsolete", "too chatty", and "not constructive" reasons - a catch-all for all non-useful but non-rude comments. So "was the comment  truly obsolete?" is the wrong question to ask. NLN can be perfectly valid on comments that are not obsolete, but rather just never had any value to start with.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't quote the comment in question (which is now deleted). I'm all for having discussions about diamond moderator actions out in the open so that we can see how the sausage is made, debate their actions, and hold them accountable for missteps - but that requires disclosing enough information for us to be able to understand what's being discussed. This question is pretty meaningless to everyone except you and the mods as it stands. (Edit: Oh, I see the invisible link to a screenshot in the markdown. Suggest transcribing it to make the text visible, and the username less so.)